# how to check which flavor of android the user is running

Tags: android, version

is there a way to do this in code? Say for example I want to know if the user is using froyo and if they are, do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [android.os.Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

You have several ways to check such as comparing agsinst `CODENAME` or `SDK version code`